# RDBMS Relational Algebra Example

Tags: sql, oop, relational-database

I am working on implementing a Relational Database Management System for a school project. The system generates pseudo-SQL commands based on what the user enters into an interactive system. These commands are passed through a parser, which translates the line into actual function calls that the engine can execute.

I feel like I understand fairly well the operations that the database needs to perform in an SQL sense, but I'm unsure of how to translate those tasks to a procedural language that can actually carry out those operations.

I'm trying to find one or more examples of a relational algebra system implemented in an object oriented language like C++ or Java, so I can get an idea of what might work for my design. If anyone has an example they can share with me, that would be greatly appreciated. It doesn't need to be super complicated (in fact I would prefer the opposite), I am just trying to get an idea of how I might translate operations like selection or projection into an actual programming language.

Comment: You want us to write an RDBMS for you? I would suggest that you choose a less ambitious project, one that builds on your past achievements.

Comment: No, not at all. I was just looking for some examples. I have found plenty of resources on how relational algebra works, but much less regarding how it would actually look as code. As I said this is a school project.

Comment: You could examine the source code of an open-source RDBMS such as MySQL. However, I think that you will find that pretty heavy going. There may be some academic 'toy' RDBMS's around, but I'm not aware of any. Other than that, you may have to consult textbooks. You could try asking at [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give that a try.

Comment: Another approach would be to write a translator to convert pseudo-SQL into commands for a NoSQL database (which may well be what you want). Take a look at [TXL](http://www.txl.ca/). It's a rule-driven general-purpose text translation system. The learning curve is a bit steep but you may find it useful. Unfortunately, there is no ready-made SQL grammar for it as far as I'm aware.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but I doubt it would fly with the professor's requirements. But I will look into it if it can help me understand how to approach this assignment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will have to create a grammar and translation rules -- stuff that you will need to do anyway. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [SIRA_PRISE](http://shark.armchair.mb.ca/~erwin/) - a "Straightforward Implementation of a Relational Algebra - Prototype of a Relational Information Storage Engine".